# How to select dynamic javascript dom element

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, dom

I created a javascript script to create a couple of divs. Now i want to use javascript again but i can't get a way of doing it.

```
 data.map((_r) => {
    classesList.innerHTML += `
    <div class="class" name=${_r.name} >
          <div class="top">
            <h1>${_r.name}</h1>
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom">
            <p>${_r.count}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    `;
  });
```

Using the `document.querySelectorAll(".class")` to get the inserted elements returns an empty NodeList

Comment: Is the "classesList" appended to the document.body?

Comment: When are you running querySelectorAll()? Perhaps the elements are not loaded to the DOM when you run it.

Comment: Have you check the `divs` are added? I make a test and your querySelectorAll is correct.

Comment: #The KNVB the classesList appends to another div not the body

Comment: Yea #Rarex, they are not loaded to the dom yet. but using DOMNodeLoaded event fires many times than i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
data = [{ name:'Steve',count:10 },{name:'Everst',count:1}];
let html='';
data.map((_r) => {
  html += `
  <div class="class" name=${_r.name} >
      <div class="top">
          <h1>${_r.name}</h1>
          <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
          <p>${_r.count}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  `;
});
document.body.innerHTML=html;
let divs = document.querySelectorAll(".class");
console.log(divs)
```